# Swift: Json parse in two pickerView between country and city

Tags: json, swift, uipickerview

I have two JSON Url. want to parse between two UIPickerView. one UIPickerView for Country, and another one for the city. I have been able to parse JSON in first UIPickerView of Country, in here data is coming perfectly. but I got a thread message in DidSelectRow func when clicking UIPickerView of the city. please try to solve this problem

here is my code.

```
var arrCountryPicker = [CountryPicker]()

 var arrCitiPicker = [CityPicker]()

    var id = 0
    var country_id = 0
```

**my two URL**

`let url = URL(string: "http://......./mobile-app/countries")`

`let url = URL(string: "http://......../mobile-app/city-by-country-id?country_id="+String(country_id))`

**PickerViewCode**

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {


    var country: Int = arrCountryPicker.count

    if pickerView == cityPickerView {

        country = self.arrCitiPicker.count
    }
    return country
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if pickerView == countryPickerView {

        let titleRow = arrCountryPicker[row].name

        return titleRow

    } else if pickerView == cityPickerView{
        let titleRow = arrCitiPicker[row].name

        return titleRow
    }
    return ""
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    countryTextField.text = arrCountryPicker[row].name

    if pickerView == countryPickerView {
        self.countryTextField.text = self.arrCountryPicker[row].name
        self.country_id = self.arrCountryPicker[row].id!
        self.countryPickerView.isHidden = true
    }
    else if pickerView == cityPickerView{
```

> **Thread about down code is "Thread 1: exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_1386_invop,subcode=0x0)**

```
        self.cityTextField.text = self.arrCitiPicker[row].name

        self.cityPickerView.isHidden = true

    }
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}


func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if (textField == countryTextField){
        self.countryPickerView.isHidden = false

    }
    else if (textField == cityTextField){
        self.cityPickerView.isHidden = false

    }

}
```

Comment: Make sure your outlets are all connected. It may be that your `cityTextField` outlet isn't connected.

Comment: Try if let also. May be value is nil. try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871398/thread-1-exc-bad-instruction-code-exc-1386-invop-subcode-0x0

Comment: in which line u faced this issue bro

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik `self.cityTextField.text = self.arrCitiPicker[row].name` in line didselectRow func

Comment: are you connected the cityTextField in your current class

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik what you try to mean please. the cityTextField and countryTextFiled in same class. both pickerView also in same class

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik my project goes to crash by thread when click cityTexField

Comment: are you connected the cityTextField.text in your current class

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i am doing every programmatically. here everything in a class.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik how to connect textField in current class.... `self.textField` this is ok

Comment: is this possible to attach your projec

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i am Azmal Tech. here i posted my all codes https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154116/ios-developer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i am go to lunch now because of hungry. i will come a hour later. it is office rule. now i am in office

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the thread is gone but now cityPickerView show nothing

Comment: cityPickerView show nothing means data not shows or error does not shows brp

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik post picture about my project in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154116/ios-developer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik now i have this " fatal error: Index out of range"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update array of city picker whenever you change Country.

In did select of Country picker, Call web service for particular country id and update array of Cities.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    //Remove this line
    //txtCountry.text = self.arrCountries[row].name

    if pickerView == CountryPicker {
        self.txtCountry.text = self.arrCountries[row].name
        self.country_id = self.arrCountryPicker[row].id!

        //Update city array according selected country
        self.updateCitiesFor(id: row)

        self.CountryPicker.isHidden = true
    }  else if pickerView == cityPicker {
        self.txtCity.text = self.arrCities[row].name
        self.cityPicker.isHidden = true
    }
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

func for update arrCitiPicker

```
func updateCitiesFor(id: Int) {

    let url = URL(string: "http://......../mobile-app/\(id)")

    //Call web service and store cities data of selected country into arrCitiPicker

    //Clear city textfield when country change
    self.txtCity.text = ""     

    //Update City Picker with new data
    cityPicker.reloadAllComponents()
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. what i have to write for update arrCityPicker

Comment: Call web service for cities and add response data into array. But first print your cities array. Your error may be have nil value.

Comment: i got thread on this line `self.cityTextField.text = self.arrCitiPicker[row].name` after use your new code. also console message is `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
fatal error: Index out of range`

Comment: Just print your arrCitiPicker after update array in updateCitiesFor() function. What is display in debug area?

Comment: it print nothing `print(  "city picker \(self.cityPickerDataLoad(id: row))")`

Comment: please come to this chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154116/ios-developer

Comment: now print in debug   city picker ()
city picker ()
city picker ()
city picker ()

Comment: i am going to contact to my co_worker who make php file

Comment: problem is when do not have data in cityURL. project goes to crash. `if self.arrCitiPicker[row].name != "" {
                self.cityTextField.text = self.arrCitiPicker[row].name
            }`  got thread in `   if self.arrCitiPicker[row].name != "" {
               `